# CI tool for React Native

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration, circleci, fastlane, bitrise

Which CI tool do you use for your React Native project? I currently shortlisted 4 but interested what are pros and cons of each of them or any others:

- https://www.bitrise.io/
- https://fastlane.tools/
- https://circleci.com/
- https://nevercode.io/

Answer (score 3):

Viktor from Bitrise.

Won't comment on other tools just a couple of highlights for Bitrise:

- We have an open source runner (https://www.bitrise.io/cli), which is pretty similar to fastlane; you can install it on your Mac/PC and run your config there without even registering on bitrise.io
- We have project scanner for React Native projects, also open source (https://github.com/bitrise-core/bitrise-init). This usually means that by running `bitrise init` on your Mac in the RN project repo root, or by registering the repo on bitrise.io you'll get a suitable base build configuration for your RN project out-of-the-box.
- That said, once the base config is generated you're free to tweak/modify it in any way you like (similar to a fastlane config). For this you can edit the config yml directly, or use our Workflow Editor UI which can also be used both on bitrise.io and locally on your Mac/PC. Related guide with more info about this: https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/how-to-experiment-with-bitrise-configs-locally-on-your-mac-linux/1751

Obviously there are many more features, for those our DevCenter should be a good starting point (http://devcenter.bitrise.io/), I just wanted to highlight a couple of points directly for your use case / for your question.

We're always happy to answer any questions you might have, and it's also worth to check our DevCenter and the community forum (https://discuss.bitrise.io/) as usually you can find your answer in these :)

Comment: Also note that you're free to use fastlane on bitrise.io as the runner, we have built in support for that, if you'd rather use fastlane for the config & runner instead of our CLI.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain an open-source RN SDK and contribute to Fastlane. I use Fastlane for CI in the repo as well as repo maintenance: https://github.com/BranchMetrics/react-native-branch-deep-linking/blob/master/fastlane/Fastfile. The repo has two jobs, one on Travis and one on Circle, because until recently, neither one supported using the Android SDK on OS X. Circle recently added support for this: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/android-and-ios-support-in-the-same-project/12102. I haven't tried it yet.

I don't have any experience using Fastlane to build and distribute RN apps, but I know a number of RN apps use it, including this one:

https://github.com/infinitered/ChainReactApp/blob/master/ios/fastlane/Fastfile
https://github.com/infinitered/ChainReactApp/blob/master/android/fastlane/Fastfile

Fastlane is extensible and has a very active community that has produced a large number of plugins for different purposes: https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/available-plugins/.

Comment: Note: bitrise.io also has stacks with both iOS tools (Xcode) and Android tools installed.